# Add features to watch clips (on Wikipedia)

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, ios-app, videos, wikipedia

I read [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158824/41634) and in the comment there is a link to [this wiki page](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yo-yo_de-spin), which has a clip on that. I cannot watch it inside the app. I use iPad2.

[image]

Comment: Can't fix since the solution lies somewhere between Apple and Wikipedia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is a problem with the app, but more with Wikipedia, and iOS in general. I opened the link in mobile Chrome, and still wasn't able to play the video.

EDIT (h/t Shadow Wizard): See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_and_Adobe_Flash_controversy -- iOS *can't* play Flash videos.

Comment: I haven't tested the sound, but that clip works on Chrome on Windows (8). (*I don't have an iPad*)

Comment: Yup. Apple does not allow Flash: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_and_Adobe_Flash_controversy

Comment: This one actually isn't Flash's fault. :)  The video is an OGG file which plays natively in desktop Chrome but is Apple doesn't support.  On desktop Safari it actually plays in a Java plugin, but mobile Safari doesn't support Java either.  Wikipedia could encode in an Apple-friendly format as well but I assume there's moral and CDN budget implications.

Comment: @BrianNickel what moral and CDN budget implications are you talking about?